# select the same day each month for the past 2 years or any year

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I'm working on recurring payment monthly. How do I select the same day each month for the past 2 years using SQL?

Example:

Send "23-11-2017" to get all records that have been added on the same day

Or

Send "31-01-2018" to get all records that have been added on the same day but not all months have a 31st day.

How can I get all records that have been added on the same day?

Comment: Please define what to do for 2017-01-31.

Comment: user pay for service and i want to get pay for this service every month in the same day @GordonLinoff

Comment: But if that day does not exist, what to do than?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the `DAY()` function?

```
SELECT
*
FROM table
WHERE DAY(date_column) = 28;
```

#### Resources

- [Manual - MySQL DAY()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-day-function.php)